# Select last occurence of key in dataset

Tags: dataset, filtering

I have a large `Dataset` filled with data from a SQL DB. I sort the set via name and date with the `SelectBy` function and get something like this:[image]

In the end, I want a reduced `Dataset` with only one entry (with the youngest SQLDateTime) per `"ID"` (first column). 
My question is now, how can I select the last occurrence of each `"ID"` listed in the first row?

**Sample Data**

```
$dataset = Dataset @* Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "Value1", "Value2"} -> #]&] @
  { {"CAV00009", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}], 1., 31.}
  , {"CAV00009", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 1., 139.}
  , {"CAV00009", SQLDateTime[{2013, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}], Null, 720.}
  , {"CAV00009", SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 8, 19, 40, 0.}], Null, 720.}
  , {"CAV00009", SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 2, 21, 50, 0.}], Null, 720.}
  , {"CAV00010", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 12, 0, 2, 0.}], 1., 30.}
  , {"CAV00010", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], 1., 123.9}
  , {"CAV00010", SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], Null, 720.}
  , {"CAV00010", SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 24, 19, 45, 0.}], Null, 786.}
  , {"CAV00010", SQLDateTime[{2013, 6, 1, 17, 0, 0.}], Null, 786.2}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0.}], 1., 30.}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 23, 20, 50, 0.}], 1., 139.}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}], 2, 720.}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 24, 20, 35, 0.}], Null, 732.}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 4, 22, 0, 0.}], Null, 786.}
  , {"CAV00011", SQLDateTime[{2013, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}], Null, 720.}
}
```

Comment: You need something like `ds[GroupBy[#ID &]][All, Last]`, where `ds` is your data set. Generally, it is better to provide explicit small sample in your question, to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$dataset[GroupBy[#ID &] /* Values, Last]
```

To see why, let's build it up step-by-step.  First, we will use `GroupBy` to gather together all of the rows for each ID:

```
$dataset[GroupBy[#ID &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Next, we will extract the last element from each group:

```
$dataset[GroupBy[#ID &], Last]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This is almost our desired result, except that we still have the lingering grouping keys from the first step.  We remove them using `Values`:

```
$dataset[GroupBy[#ID &] /* Values, Last]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This is our final result.

**What if the original data were unsorted?**

If we had no guarantee that the original data was presented in sorted order, we can still find the latest row in each group using `MaximalBy`:

```
$dataset[GroupBy[#ID &] /* Values, MaximalBy[#Date &] /* First]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Note the use of `First` in the subexpression `MaximalBy[...] /* First`.  This is necessary because `MaximalBy` always returns a list of all elements that are maximal.  The use of `First` is arbitrary, and could just as easily be `Last`.  It only makes a difference if there a multiple maximal entries.  If multiple maxima are a possibility, and we care about which one we select, then we should consider expanding the list of inspected components to reflect our preference (e.g. `MaximalBy[{#Date, #Value1, #Value2}&]`).

Comment: I'm really impressed by this forum! You even made my question better by adding a usable sample. The answers works of course. And the last idea with the `MaximalBy` is very useful.

Comment: There is just one question left, why do you use `$dataset` instead of `dataset`?

Comment: @Lea As to the dollar sign in `$dataset`, see the [second FAQ in my profile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach).

Comment: @WReach, what if you're using 3rd party APIs that either also use $prefix or start with Uppercase?

Comment: @alancalvitti To resolve name collisions, I usually choose one of two strategies.  If the number of uses of a colliding name is small, then I just use the fully qualified name.  If there are a large number of references, then I define a short alias instead.  While I can think a few instances where I have had to deal with a function name collision, I can't think of a case where I have had to deal with colliding global variables.  Global variable names tend to be very specialized.